# Address of de-referenced pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am working on someone else code at work (Qt Desktop application) and found this:

```
connect( &*mpMainWin, SIGNAL(whatever()), this, SLOT(whatever()) ));
```

I have some difficulties to understand the part `&*mpMainWin`. As far as I know about pointers, it returns the address of the de-referenced pointer `mpMainWin`.

But `mpMainWin` already hold that address, so giving it directly as a parameter should have the same result.

So if I'm not missing anything and my logic is right, what is the reason of doing such a thing? and if there is one when should we use that kind of syntax?

Comment: Does the type of `mpMainWin` have an overloaded dereference operator?

Comment: No I don't find any overloading in its header.

Comment: How about for its superclass(es)?  Did you try taking out the `&*` to see what happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be used as a trick to convert a smart pointer (i.e. not really a pointer, a class implementing `operator*()`) into a plain pointer.  Without seeing how `mpMainWin` is declared it is impossible to say if that's the case here.  If `mpMainWin` is a plain pointer to begin with then yes, `&*mpMainWin` is the same as just `mpMainWin`.